# Can't call overriden toSting()

Tags: c#

I just start with c#.
I want to override toString() method with parameter. i do:

```
    public string ToString(bool param)
    {
        if (param)
        {
            return string.Format(FIO);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Format(Address);
        }
    }
```

And call it:

```
myClass.toString(true);
```

But get error:

```
method toString() has 0 parameters but invoked with 1 argument.
```

Whats can be wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the code that makes the call?

Comment: C# is case sensitive.  Your method is "ToString", but you are calling "toString"

Comment: Compare `toString()` with `ToString()` - Hint: Case sensitivity

Comment: _Note:_ you are not overriding; this is called function/method overloading.

Comment: ps2goat right i have a typo in method have. I fixed it but get same error.

Comment: or perhaps you should call 'toSting()' based on your question title.

Comment: @KliverMax please update your sample code above to match what you currently have.  These typos between your actual code and what you post here can be the difference in fixing it within minutes vs. fixing it within weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string ToString(bool param)
    {
        return param.ToString();
    }
}
```

This code will work as expected:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
string s = myClass.ToString(true);
```

Therefore you have an error in part of the code that you are not showing us.

Possibilities:

Typo in the method name?
Using the wrong class?

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive. Your method is "ToString", but you are calling "toString"

change

```
myClass.toString(true);
```

to

```
myClass.ToString(true); // <-- capital T
```

Comment: While that is correct, why would that give the compilation error in the question?

Comment: Good point.  If the two case issues were reversed, e.g., .NET Framework's was lower case, that would cause this error.  We'll have to wait until the op posts his actual code.

Answer (score 0):

to override - you need to use the override keyword. However, you cannot override the default ToString() method since it is parameterless so you cannot "modify" it to add a parameter thus you need to create another method.

but your example does not work anyway. C# is case sensitive so you need to call:

```
myClass.ToString(true)
```

NOT:

```
myClass.toString(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error is telling you exactly what is wrong.

When overriding a method (where you missed the "override") keyword you have to keep the parameters. So you can overwrite .ToString(), but not .ToString(bool something)

As you surely want to achive something completely different than the .ToString()-Method I would simply advice to write a complete own method instead of overwriting

My Suggestion would be:

```
public override string ToString() {
   return string.Format(Address);
} 
public string ToStringParam() {
   return string.format(FIO);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong ToString from the base class. For a reason the complier does not find the correct to string; Maybe you are casting somewhere the object.

For this problem; I recommend you to use the Extension Methods:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
  public static class MyExtensions
  {

    // I DONOT KNOW YOUR OBJECT TYPE I JUST HAVE USED A DUMMY THING; YOU CAN REPLACE IT!!!!
    public static string ToString(this MyType myClass, bool param)
    {
          if (param)
          {
             return string.Format(myClass.FIO);
          }

             return string.Format(myClass.Address);
     }
   }   
}
```